# Does the Nokia web 40 app developer platform read CSS prefixes

Tags: css, webkit, nokia

I have tested some -web-kit prefixes in a Web 40 app and noticed it isn't reading the css code.  Can anyone confirm what the Nokia Asha browser is based on, and how I should tweak my css to comply.

Comment: Have you tried providing non-prefixed versions of each property as well?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm tapping into some cool -webkit stuff.

Comment: Be responsible with your prefixes:  http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2012/02/09/CALL-FOR-ACTION:-THE-OPEN-WEB-NEEDS-YOU-NOW

Answer (score 0):

The Nokia browser is called Nokia Xpress that's the only thing I can be sure